# Spring jar versions are not compatible and therefore I am getting compiler errors. Need help in identifying which dependency is causing the issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-camel

I have the following pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.cnt.orchtn</groupId>
        <artifactId>orchtn-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../../orchtn-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>

    </parent>

    <groupId>com.dsfsdaf.orchtn</groupId>
    <artifactId>orchen-con-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-RELEASE</version>
    <name>OrchServi</name>
    <description>Orch</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <camel.version>3.1.0</camel.version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
        <kafka.version>2.6.0</kafka.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-kafka-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
             <!--  <version>2.10.0</version> -->
             <version>2.11.3</version> 
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20200518</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <!-- This dependency is for WebClient implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.jolt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jolt-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.jolt</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-utils</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
         <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfrog.buildinfo</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifactory-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
         -->


    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cnc-clg-srd-cbf-artifactory--cnc-clg-srd-cbf-artifactory</id>
            <name>cnc-clg-srd-cbf-artifactory--cnc-clg-srd-cbf-artifactory</name>
            <url>https://cnc-clg-srd-cbf-artifactory-255474220078.d.codeartifact.us-east 
                        1.amazonaws.com/maven/cnc-clg-srd-cbf-artifactory/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>Maven-Artifactory-Plugin</id>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory--cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory</id>
            <name>cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory--cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory</name>
            <url>https://cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory-255474220078.d.codeartifact.us-east
                 1.amazonaws.com/maven/cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>

          </plugin> 
                
                
            <!-- <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin> -->
            <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have the following parent pom file:

```
      <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.cnt.orctr</groupId>
    <artifactId>orctr-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description>Orch Parent</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>



     <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <version>5.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.11</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
     </dependencyManagement>

     <profiles>
            <profile>
                <id>cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory--cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory</id>
                <activation>
                      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                </activation>
            <repositories>
               <repository>
                   <id>cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory--cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory</id>
                   <name>cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory--cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory</name>
                   <url>https://cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory-255474220078.d.codeartifact.us-east
                         1.amazonaws.com/maven/cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory/</url>
              </repository>
          </profile>
        </profiles>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>Maven-Artifactory-Plugin</id>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory--cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory</id>
            <name>cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory--cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory</name>
            <url>https://cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory-255474220078.d.codeartifact.us-east 
                    1.amazonaws.com/maven/cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory/</url>
        </repository>

    </distributionManagement>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>11</source>
                        <target>11</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!--<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                </plugin>-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jfrog.buildinfo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>artifactory-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>build-info</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>publish</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactory>
                                    <includeEnvVars>true</includeEnvVars>
                                    <envVarsExcludePatterns>*password*,*secret*,*key*,*token*,*passphrase*</envVarsExcludePatterns>
                                    <timeoutSec>60</timeoutSec>
                                </artifactory>
                                <publisher>
                                    <contextUrl>https://cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory-255474220078.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory/</contextUrl>
                                    <username>aws</username>
                                    <password>${env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN}</password>
                                    <repoKey>libs-release-local</repoKey>
                                    <snapshotRepoKey>libs-snapshot-local</snapshotRepoKey>
                                </publisher>
                                <!-- <buildInfo> <buildName>centene-framework</buildName> <buildNumber>${buildnumber}</buildNumber> 
                                    <buildUrl>http://build-url.org</buildUrl> </buildInfo> -->
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

   </project>
```

I am able to compile and deploy the parent project into the repository.  The problem is with the child project which I am not able to compile, it is throwing build failures.  It is not able to resolve any dependencies which are referenced in the parent project.

Could anyone let me know what I am missing and how I can reference the parent pom in the child pom, and have all the dependencies resolved in the child project.

Note: I have seen all the child pom being referenced in many web sites.  I dont see any difference in any way that I am doing it.  Maybe noticing something here.  Could some one point out...

Comment: The issue I am facing is when I compile the child project it is throwing compile errors as it is not able to find the dependencies which are put in the parent pom file.  It is throwing compiler errors while building. Also all the references for the classes defined the java files in the child project are also broken.

Comment: What I notice is the classes to which the dependencies have be put in the parent pom are the ones which are breaking.  For instance I am using StringUtils reference in my java class in my child project.  The dependency of that is commons3.StringUtils of apache, which I have placed in the parent project pom. But that is not being referenced.

Comment: For starters stop mixing versions of a framework. You are mixing Spring Boot 2.2.6, 2.3.4 and 2.4.0 which is trouble waiting to happen. Also why should it be able to reference those dependencies, they are in a `dependencyManagement` section **not** a `dependencies` section.

Comment: Thanks for that I have removed the dependencyManagement section and kept them in dependencies section.  But as you mentioned right, the  versions are differing hence I am getting a different error when I startup the applciation.

Comment: An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location: org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.startup.StartupEndpointAutoConfiguration$ApplicationStartupCondition.getMatchOutcome                                                                            It was loaded from the following location:
    file:/C:/Users/cn249124/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar

Comment: It was loaded from the following location:
    file:/C:/Users/cn249124/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar
Action:
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory

Comment: Don't add code/stacktraces etc. as comments as those are unreadable. Also that is a different question and doesn't relate to this one. As stated don't mix dependencies from different versions as that will bite you.